# What should I as a beginning surfer consider when buying my first longboard?

Tags: gear, surfing

I'm a beginning surfer, and I want a longboard.

- How do I select one? How much should I pay?
- What is good width and length, etc.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have never surfed before, avoid going for a really long one - they are very unweildy, can be difficult to get up to speed, and are a pain to carry back to the car when you are tired out :-)

As far as width goes - can you sit up comfortably on it? And can you fit it under your arm?

[Islesurfboards](http://www.islesurfboards.com/longboard-surfing.aspx) in California have this chart, which is a pretty good starting point:

[image]

Their website also gives a lot of info on all aspects of surfing.

Comment: I bought a 9'2 surf tech k-star rapoza board. Really happy with it!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to longboards, you could investigate a mini-Malibu ("mini-mal") / mini-longboard shape, with lengths in the region of 7'*x*" - 8'*x*".

As a beginner you'll find such a board easier to control than a longboard, and thus less frustrating to use, although longboarders will out-pace you when paddling onto a wave.